# what is the best way for real-time communication between android clients?

Tags: java, android, tomcat, real-time

I have to add new functionality to an android app (4.1 api 16), java server (1.7) as backend with tomcat 7. communication over http requests and json. for the app new functionality it is required that the users can communicate in real time so I’ve found different possibilities like
long polling, websocket. server-sent events. 
any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Will probably be closed because "opinion-based" but it is an interesting question.

Comment: depends on requirement also. If the communication requirement is smaller level I suggest you use Firebase for that.

Comment: @ShubhankGupta the clients should be able to build groups in which they exchange data. Firebase is not an option, because it is not free.

Comment: but you can achieve the group chat also using the firebase

Comment: I already try by using firebase its work good for me in group chat

Answer (score 3):

It's not all about WhatsApp, there are tons of instant messengers. We’ve rounded up the best Android has to offer, so you can choose the one that best suits your individual tastes and needs.

I personally would recommend **Firebase** as one of the best real-time applications for a chat messenger. I have listed my reasons below:

```
Documentation, Support, Flexibility, Scope, Reliability, Cost, Complexity
```

Some of the Third party you can also use listed below:

> PubNub

PubNub provides over 70 different SDKs for you to develop scalable, realtime, data stream applications with globally distribute data centers and automatic replication and failover.

> OS : FreeBSD

FreeBSD is the operating system upon which WhatsApp is laid upon.
Kernel Services - Process management, Memory Management, I/O system, Inter process communication.

> YAWS (Yet another Web Server)

YAWS is an Erlang web server. Its written in Erlang and it uses Erlang as its embedded language similar to PHP in Apache.

> Ejabberd (XMPP) server

Ejabberd (XMPP) server which facilitates instant message transfer between two or many users on a real-time basis. High reliability and sustainability even under peak traffic the reason why WhatsApp developers chose Ejabberd above anything else.
The XMPP protocol has also been customized to speed up signing in and re-signing in sessions.

> Erlang

The programming language used to build massively scalable software real-time systems with requirements on high availability. Runtime system has built-in support for concurrency, distribution and fault tolerance.

PHP
Regarding the PHP integration, there are again, several ways to communicate both sides. You can integrate the chat with your PHP code using a PHP Erlang Bridge. PEB (PHP - Erlang - Bridge) is an open sour PHP extension to run PHP as an Erlang node.

> XMPP

Communication Protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML. XMPP is faster than HTTP only for real-time chat application. It ensures network security and used to trans messages.
HTML5 WebSockets which communication technology which facilitates two-way communication.

> DataBase (Mnesia)

Mnesia DB handles the heavy-duty task of database management. Mnesia is a multiuser distributed DBMS which also happens to be the default DB of ERLANG. Mnesia helps achieve quicker request responses, thereby improving the overall efficiency.

[Plz check reference url](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-technology-to-use-when-making-a-real-time-mobile-chat-notifications-application)